# DataGridView Cascading ComboBox displays black color backcolor in 2nd combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have winform application with `DataGridView` and there I am using Cascading ComboBox. For example column 1 has one `ComboBox` and value of column 2 combobox depends on column 1 selection. Everything seems to be fine but when i open 2nd combobox then its backcolor gets black. See the screenshot. I am not setting backcolor anywhere (in design or code). Any idea why this strange behavior?
[image: sceenshot]

I am binding 2nd ComboBox in EditingControlShowing event of `DataGridView`. If i bind that in FromLoad event then it works fine.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just ran into the same problem, and it appears to have to do with accessing a cell's EditedFormattedValue, although I'm not exactly sure why

Comment: Old post, but in my case it happened that I called `SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);` within `EditingControlShowing` event before clearing and filling again the ComboBox control. The cause of the problem was that call for suspending redraw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In combobox `DropDown` event I am setting `BackColor = Color.White;`. So its a workaround I found for now. Any other solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `DefaultCellStyle` of the column.  It's the only place I see where I can duplicate the blackness.

Answer (score 2):

it's an old post but someone might need this like me. Why not try:

```
cmbBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted);
```

instead of:

```
cmbBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```